# Pip not found error when installing wkhtmltopdf while building Docker image

Tags: python, docker, pip, wkhtmltopdf

When I try to build the image I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip3", line 5, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip._internal.cli.main'
```

This is my dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.8-slim-buster
WORKDIR /app
COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

RUN pip install python3-wkhtmltopdf
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y wkhtmltopdf
COPY . .
CMD [ "python3", "app.py"]
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are actually trying to install [py3-wkhtmltopdf](https://pypi.org/project/py3-wkhtmltopdf/). To do this, you can just leverage `python -m pip` and install the package directly:

```
FROM python:3.8-slim-buster
WORKDIR /app

# following their linux installation instructions
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
  xvfb \
  xfonts-100dpi xfonts-75dpi xfonts-scalable xfonts-cyrillic \
  wkhtmltopdf

COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN python -m pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . .
CMD [ "python", "app.py"]
```

Where `requirements.txt` might look like:

```
py3-wkhtmltopdf
```